# C program to create assembly for reading integer

Tags: c, interrupt, inline-assembly

I want to create a library in C using inline assembly language program of x86 along with int $128 (software interrupt) for GCC assembler for reading integer inputs . How to proceed ?

To print an integer I've used following :-

```
#define BUFF 20
int print_int(int n){ // print_int.c
char buff[BUFF], zero='0';
int i=0, j, k, bytes;
if(n == 0) buff[i++]=zero;
else{
   if(n < 0) {
   buff[i++]='-';
   n = -n;
 }



while(n){
   int dig = n%10;
   buff[i++] = (char)(zero+dig);
   n /= 10;
}
if(buff[0] == '-') 
   j = 1;
else 
   j = 0;
k=i-1;
while(j<k){
   char temp=buff[j];
   buff[j++] = buff[k];
   buff[k--] = temp;
  }
}


buff[i]='\n';
bytes = i+1;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
  "movl $4, %%eax \n\t"
  "movl $1, %%ebx \n\t"
  "int $128 \n\t"
  :
  :"c"(buff), "d"(bytes)
) ; // $4: write, $1: on stdin

return bytes-1;
}
```

Likewise I want to know for reading integers.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: `print_int(int n) { printf("%d\n", n); }`
`read_int(int *n) { scanf("%d", n); }`

Comment: What does this give you? If it's not what you want what specifically do you want to be produced?

Comment: I want to do without using standard libraries but rather using inline assembly language with software interrupt (using _asm_ _volatile_)

Comment: Start by indenting your code.

Comment: done @AlexReynolds...i hope now I get my answer

Comment: i guess the most important part is to properly initialize `%eax` so that os may choose proper service routine. you may also want to modify service routine table by yourself

Comment: @mangusta...can you give me a working code or any sources as such?

Comment: @user3924392 i haven't found it specifically for stdin read but i guess it is all same if you follow manuals about issuing system call from user program

Answer (score 0):

Your asm statement needs a clobber list as it modifies eax and ebx, and depends upon the contents of memory that isn't listed as an input (the contents of buff, only the address of buff is listed as an input). At present the compiler will assume that it doesn’t.

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
  "movl $4, %%eax \n\t"
  "movl $1, %%ebx \n\t"
  "int $128 \n\t"
  :
  :"c"(buff), "d"(bytes)
  :"%eax", "%ebx", "memory"
)
```

Comment: He might also want to consider replacing the movs with input constraints: `"a" (4), "b" (1)`. This way you can avoid the eax+ebx clobbers (still need memory), and allow the compiler to move the values into the registers whenever it is convenient, AND to re-use the eax+ebx values in later code.

Comment: Also, I'm not on linux, but isn't eax where the return value from the interrupt is?  Maybe use `"=a" (retval)` for output and `"0" (4)` for input?

Comment: @Timothy Baldwin ...actually my code written in _asm_ _volzatile_ works fine for printing integers...I want to know the same code for READING integers...hope you can help

Comment: What Timothy is trying to say is that your code DOESN'T work fine.  While it may appear to work under certain circumstances, if your asm changes the values of registers without letting gcc know, strange problems may appear, sometimes long after the asm statement.  The changes I proposed may (slightly) improve performance.  Correctly writing code with asm can be quite challenging, and in almost all cases, you should use library functions instead.  But if you MUST use interrupts, http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/ may give you some ideas about what to put in which registers for the various calls.